# flask render_template not working with anchor tag # - jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound

Tags: flask, anchor, template-engine, jinja2

In the url_for method, you can pass in an _anchor parameter to load up an anchor tag on page load.

How would i do the same thing with render_template ?

I can

```
render_template('profile/index.html')
```

without any issues but when i add the anchor tag at the end of the html and try to do

```
render_template('profile/index.html#h1")
```

I get the template not found error

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound
TemplateNotFound: profile/index.html#h1
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? `render_template` and `url_for` do two very different things. `render_template` takes the name of the template file to load. The `#` provides no special meaning in this context.

Comment: Thanks Dim for taking time here to help me out. Might be im not thinking abt it the right way here. I have a page with 3 tabs and one of them has a form in it. When i submit the form, i process it and want to render the page back with the same tab open. If i do a URL redirect, I could load up the form tab but i lose the form value entries. Setting the form entries to session and pulling them back would be a solution but seems a little crude ?

Comment: A good way to solve that is how you could do with WT-Forms, to have something like populate_obj. And render_template will only take in the file name of the template and anything to do with links should go to url_for

Comment: You probably just want to pass a value to the template that indicates which tab to render. `render_template('profile/index.html', active_tab='...')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially thats what I ended up doing, I passed in a value along with the render_template

```
return render_template('profile/index.html', set_tab=1)
```

On the client side in javascript, i did the following to set the tab

```
<script>
   var obj_load={% if set_tab==1%}1{%else%}0{%endif%};
   tab_load=(obj_load?"#h1":"#");

   $(document).ready(function () {
       if(location.hash || obj_load) {
       $('a[href=' + (location.hash ||  tab_load) + ']').tab('show');
       }
    });

</script>
```

fyi, im using bootstrap 3's tab-pane