# Flask WTForm after validated form return upper index.html but form is bottom index

Tags: html, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms

`index.html` file is divided in sections, each one have variable size depending content. It has navigation bar that links to contact section at bottom page.  Simplifying index is like this

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block content %}
<header class="masthead">
</header>
<section class="page-section bg-light" id="portfolio">
</section>
<section class="page-section" id="contact">
</section>
{% endblock content %}
```

In views.py the route is passing the form, there it is.

```
@main.route('/home', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def home():
    form = ContactUs()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        print(form.data)
        ......
    return render_template('index.html', title='Home', form=form)
```

when user left values empty  or email is not correct and he/she summit it, validation detected and return messages so user can fill it out or correct mistake.

[image]

However index is reloaded after validation, it return to upper section and contact section is out view.  I don't find too much information when form is embedded into webpage and no one related to validation.  There is a lot related to simple forms.

If user does not see errors message never it will send but user could have idea that it was done.

how can it reload after validation to contact section instead upper section?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a parameter to `render_template()` indicating an anchor position on your page. Then you can use that to update the page location, similar to how it was done in this question: [flask render_template not working with anchor tag # - jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26770657/flask-render-template-not-working-with-anchor-tag-jinja2-exceptions-template)

Comment: `render_template()` is set in views.py The first time user access to "contactus" is rendered it, then user let empty or wrong filled values.  Form is validate by `if form.validate_on_submit():` and return the validation to page as shown in the picture.  It that moment is happening the undesired behavior when: page is refreshing and return to upper page instead to return Form that is bottom page

Comment: The code under `if form.validate_on_submit():` is only executed if validation was successful. To manually set display options for validation errors, you could use `form.is_submitted() and not form.validate()`.